# what is solr web interface url

Tags: solr, datastax

I am using `datastax 2.2.2` in my `ubuntu:12.04` system. I just downloaded `tar ball` and started solr using

```
 dse cassandra -s
```

It starts solr. I verified it using

```
netstat -plten
```

It show `port 8983` is being used.

```
 10.XX.XX.XX:8983/solr/ --> Call never ends. It's keep on loading.
```

I started `opscenter` and checked with `ip:8888/` it shows `opscenter ui`.

What is the solr web interface url for datastx 2.2.2 and Do i need to change any configurations for solr?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The Solr Admin UI default is usually:

```
<ip>:8983/solr
```

For example from my test VM on my local machine:

```
http://192.168.56.20:8983/solr/
```